# Extend protocol to satisfy one of multiple constraints

Tags: swift

I want to extend a protocol to satisfy one of multiple constraints. I know how to satisfy multiple constraints with (,), but that would conform to all of them.

Example:

```
protocol Abc { ... }
protocol xyz { ... }
protocol my  { ... }

extenstion  Abc where Self: xyz, Self: my {
...

}
```

I want `Abc` to either conform to `xyz` or `my`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a common protocol to do this:

```
protocol Common {  }
protocol Abc {  }
protocol xyz: Common {  }
protocol my: Common  {  }

extension Abc where Self: Common {

}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Protocol is very flexible that you can confirm any protocol any time.

Comment: this is a good one . but can't there any other way to do this?  i mean can't we do this by || operator in where clause?